# How to use qemu with "-nographic" and "-monitor stdio" at the same time?

Tags: qemu

I'm using [panda](https://github.com/panda-re/panda) (a platform based on [qemu](https://qemu.org/)) to analyze ubuntu.
I am running it in a server device so I can only get a remote terminal to operate.

Panda needs stdio to operate with the virtual machine. In normal situation the command will be like below:
`panda-system-x86_64 -m 1G -monitor stdio -show-cursor  ubuntu-2204.qcow2 -loadvm test`

When I run that under a system with GUI, it will open the virtual machine and a terminal with [qemu monitor](https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/system/monitor.html) to operate with.
[image: Nomally start]

But when I use "-nographic" to disable the GUI in
`panda-system-x86_64 -m 1G -monitor stdio -show-cursor  ubuntu-2204.qcow2 -loadvm test -nographic`

It seems that the 'stdio' device has been used by multiple device.
[image: Error occured]

When I remove the "-monitor stdio"
`panda-system-x86_64 -m 1G -show-cursor  ubuntu-2204.qcow2 -loadvm test -nographic`
It will enter the terminal of the guest ubuntu system.

[image: Need to change to qemu monitor]

At this time, I need to change it with(ctrl c-a) to the qemu monitor.

I think there might be some ways to fix that:

1. "-nographic" will use the 'stdio' as output, how could I change that?
2. Is there any way I can call up the GUI through the remote terminal?
3. The panda need 'stdio' to operate because it use the python subprogress module as followed:
       `p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = panda_stdout, stderr = panda_stderr)`
   'cmd' is the command to run panda as above.
   Is there any way to change 'stdio' to other way to operate with the guest system in order to avoid the conflict?
4. When I get a terminal like the last picture shown, how could I send a "ctrl c-a" through the 'stdio' of the subprocess to get the qemu monitor ?

Answer (score 0):

QEMU's "-nographic" option is a "do what I mean" kind of option which does a lot of things at once: it turns off the GUI window, and it also makes stdio be a multiplexed serial + QEMU monitor (and some other less important things). If you don't want all of those things, it's usually better to control all the behaviours separately.

The option to just disable the GUI window and do nothing else is "-display none". You can then use "-monitor stdio" to put the monitor on the terminal as normal.

You'll also need to figure out how you want to interact with the guest if you don't have a graphical terminal to do it. You can do that with some -serial option if the guest supports a serial terminal, or you can configure the guest to accept ssh connections and ssh into it. Or you can look into having a graphical display using VNC or Spice if what you want is a GUI display that will work well across a network connection.